# create Hyperlink to network drive folder dynamically

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-formula

I try to use in MS Excel 2013 the Hyperlink function to create a link to a folder on my network drive (for example \192.168.2.254).
I would that the name of the path use the content cell in the final part
For example =HYPERLINK("\192.168.2.254\myfolder", "text") where "myfolder" is the content of the B25 cell.

Anybody can help me, or know another way to solve my problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`=HYPERLINK( "\192.168.2.254\" & B25 , "text")`

Comment: Glad it solved your problem. Appreciate if you then acknowledge the answer and help us to keep the site updated. Thanks....